# Android, receive data from internet app does not work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, androidhttpclient

I am completely new to android.
I am trying to build a basic app to get an idea on "android applications reading data from a server". 
To get an idea about http connection on android i created this app watching a video tutorial, i have two java classes.

HttpExample.java class,

```
package com.raveen.testingthree;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HttpExample extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    GetMethodHttp test = new GetMethodHttp();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



}
```

and getmethodhttp.java class,

```
package com.raveen.testingthree;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetMethodHttp {

public String getInternetData () throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.google.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse responce = client.execute(request);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responce.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + newLine);

        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;

    } finally {
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

this is my AndroidManifest,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HttpExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

and my layout xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHttp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Data"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         />
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

now when i run this on emulator or my android phone NOTHING IS DISPLAYED.. Just a blank white layout is visible.. what am i doing wrong here?

(i am using eclipse to program)

Comment: When you look in the Logcat, are there any stacktraces being printed out?

Comment: there are lot of lines printing out in log cat. which are Stack traces? exceptions?

Comment: They would be exceptions. It might look something like "NullPointerException at com.example.activity line 145 at com.example... It might tell us what is going wrong in the code.

Comment: ohh,, yes, there is one red line at lot of orange ones with the tag system.err. . There is an exception unknownHostException!! saying no address associating host name.. but i tried www.google.com too,, still that exception is coming.. why?

Comment: Those are printing only when i use Phone , but when i use the emulator non of those errors are printed. one nullpointerexception is there.. but still nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not change the policy to force network calls on main thread instead use [Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If you want to read html contents then use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) which allows to parse html.
If you want to read data from webservice then try VOLLEY Library.This will save your time,works more efficiently and traceable.